# Resolving errors with Webpack and ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I've read lots of other S/O posts that detail a similar problem, however I cannot find a solution for my specific issue.

I installed a node module, but I am now receiving this error message:

(syllable - is the module I installed)

```
index.js:641 ./~/syllable/problematic.json
Module parse failed: /Desktop/App/node_modules/syllable/problematic.json Unexpected token (2:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Here is my Webpack config

```
var config = {
    entry: './main.js',

    output: {
      path: './',
      filename: 'index.js',
    },

    devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 3000
    },

    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel',
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        },
        {     //<-- this line is throwing an unexpected token error
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'json'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Note: I have es2015 installed, and I have tried re-writing the webpack.config.js several times to no avail.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is trying to load a `.json` file. You currently do not have a `json-loader` setup to handle this sort of thing. Have a look at [json-loader](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader).

## Example

```
npm install --save-dev json-loader
```

### webpack.config.js

```
...
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',

      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json'
    }
  }
]
...
```

Comment: json-loader was installed, however I forgot to add it to the configuration. I have now updated the webpack config as you suggested, but I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: I edited my answer to replace the `|` with a \ to escape the `.` in your babel loader. Make sure to restart your webpack builder after changing your config. Is it still throwing the same error?

Comment: I am now getting an unexpected token error, even though the syntax appears correct.. I have updated my webpack.config.js above as per your instructions.

Comment: That's because we missed a `}` after the `query` key (right after the presets). See updated answer.

Comment: Also had to change the `test: /\.jsx$/` to `test: /\.jsx?$/` because it wasn't parsing properly. None the less, all fixed. Hurrah!

Answer (score 0):

### What is error and message

> index.js:641 ./~/syllable/problematic.json Module parse failed:
>   /Desktop/App/node_modules/syllable/problematic.json Unexpected token
>   (2:11) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file typ

### And answer

You should really read it, It clearly says that Module parse failed. It gave you file name and told you that ***You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file typ***

`json-loader` **what you need**

install json-loader with npm and add it to your config.

```
{
  test: /\.json$/,
  loader: 'json'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your regular expression does not match any file extension. If you're trying to test both .js and .jsx file remove the last `$` and replace it with `?` and remove the `|`.

```
module:{
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your suggested regex is not correct (`/.jsx?/`). It would match files files ending with `ajsx` or `0jsx`. You have to escape the `.` like this `\.jsx` (Add `?` for optional `x`.